# Disable concurrent builds for same pipeline with stages running on a single agent in azuredevops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Situation**

I'm working on an AzureDevops Server with only one agent.

I have a build pipeline:

Build pipeline (yaml)
The pipeline contains multiple stages that contains one or more job.

**Current behavior**

If the pipeline is triggered twice at the same time, the agent is assigned alternatively to each builds stages.

Example of agent process order: build1-stage1, build2-stage1, build1-stage2, build2-stage2, build1-stage3, build2-stage3, build1-stage4...

In this case the repo checkout happens again in the 2nd build which causes the 1st build to fail because it has a fresh checkout done by build2.

I have tried exclusive locks to the agent but still it doesn't work as expected for stages in a pipeline.

**Wanted behavior**

This is not something unexpected if we have more agents than build executions. But this will never be my case.

So I will prefer to lock the agent for the current build (like built-in in Jenkins).

Example of agent wanted process order: build1-stage1, build1-stage2, build1-stage3, build1-stage4, build1-stage5(latest), build2-stage1, build2-stage2, build2-stage3, build2-stage4, build2-stage5(latest)

in short the latest trigger should be in queue state and agent should get assigned to the stages after the previous build has been complete.

Comment: i dont think thats possible, only if you use a single stage\job you can guarantee that

Comment: As last comment said, I don't think it is possible if you have more than one stage in the pipeline...

Answer (score 0):

The exclusive locks works on stage level and this will not work:

```
lockBehavior: sequential

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
....
- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: B        
    steps:
.....
- stage: C
  jobs:
  - job: C    
    steps:
....
- stage: D
  jobs:
  - job: D    
    steps:
....
```

However this will work:

```
lockBehavior: sequential

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
  ....
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    steps:
  ....
  - job: C
    dependsOn: B
    steps:
  ....    
  - job: D
    dependsOn: C
    steps:
  .....
```

So you may use many jobs on one stage with locks.

Or use REST API to check active builds for the current run and you may fail the run if another exists. But that`s too complex way because you have to add some scripts to restart failed builds.

Comment: even without exclusive lock it would work for a single stage or multiple job under jobs as i have only one agent... i dont understand what is exclusive locks solving here :(

Comment: @AkashRahane no... without lock each job will run sequentially between builds even with one stage.